# Function that contains alert of random number on button click - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, button, random, alert

I have this code to try and make an alert pop up on the web page that says "your number is" + "(1-25)". Nothing happens when I press the button. Does math.random only produce a number to the console or why does this not work. Here is my code.

```
function rGen () {
 let rNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 25))
 alert(rNum + "is your number")
}


let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener('click' rGen)
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have a typo in your `addEventListener`

Comment: No that was an accident when I pasted it here, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code by missing comma (`,`) and closing parenthesis (`)`):

`button1.addEventListener('click', rGen);`

```js
function rGen () {
 let rNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 25))
 alert(rNum + " is your number")
}


let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', rGen);
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid, you're missing a `)`. You also need to put a comma between `'click'` and `'rGen'`:

```js
let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', rGen);

function rGen() {
  let rNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 25));
  alert(rNum + " is your number");
}
```

```html
<div id="button1">click</div>
```